# GeoTools: Encode into GML 3 not working

Tags: geotools, gml

I want to use GeoTools to convert collection of SimpleFeature objects to GML 3.2.1 geometry.

However, I'm dealing with this:

- Creation of XSD works with both GML 2 and 3.
- Creation of GML works only with GML 2.
- With version 3, it creates empty string.

This is the piece of code:

```
    import org.geotools.GML;
    import org.geotools.data.DataUtilities;
    import org.geotools.data.collection.ListFeatureCollection;
    import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureBuilder;
    import org.geotools.geometry.jts.WKTReader2;
    import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
    import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;
```

...

```
    SimpleFeatureType featureType = DataUtilities.createType("location", "geom:Point,name:String");

    File xsdFile = new File("C:/Dev/VTS/GML_samples/location.xsd");
    xsdFile = xsdFile.getCanonicalFile();
    xsdFile.createNewFile();
    URL xsdURL = xsdFile.toURI().toURL();
    URL baseURL = xsdFile.getParentFile().toURI().toURL();

    // Creation of XSD file using GML 3 works:
    GML xsdEncoder = new GML(GML.Version.GML3);
    FileOutputStream xsd = new FileOutputStream(xsdFile);
    xsdEncoder.setBaseURL(baseURL);
    xsdEncoder.setNamespace("location", xsdURL.toExternalForm());
    xsdEncoder.encode(xsd, featureType);
    xsd.close();

    // Simple Feature collection:
    WKTReader2 wkt = new WKTReader2();
    List<SimpleFeature> collection = new LinkedList<SimpleFeature>();
    collection.add(SimpleFeatureBuilder.build(featureType, new Object[] { wkt.read("POINT (1 2)"),"name1" }, null));
    collection.add(SimpleFeatureBuilder.build(featureType, new Object[] { wkt.read("POINT (4 4)"),"name2" }, null));

    // Creation of GML file using GML 3 doesn't work. It does work with GML 2 though:
    // GML gmlEncoder = new GML(GML.Version.GML2); // this works
    GML gmlEncoder = new GML(GML.Version.GML3); // this doesn't work
    ByteArrayOutputStream xml = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    gmlEncoder.setLegacy(true);
    gmlEncoder.setBaseURL(baseURL);
    gmlEncoder.setNamespace("location", "location.xsd");
    gmlEncoder.encode(xml,  new ListFeatureCollection(featureType, collection));
    xml.close();

    System.out.println(xml.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the GML encoder silently ignores `Version.GML3` and thus you get no output! I've filed a [bug report](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOT-6078) and put in a [PR](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/pull/1992) to throw an exception if this happens.

If you want to write GML3 out you should use `Version.WFS1_1` instead.